# Android Unparseable date (at offset 0)

Tags: java, android, date, rss

I am trying to parse string date `"04 Nov 2016 16:30:07 +0300"`

My formatter is `SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH)`

And the code is `Date date = DATE_IN_FORMAT.parse(dateStr.trim());`

I keep getting exception `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "04 Nov 2016 16:30:07 +0300" (at offset 0)`

I tried switching Locale to `Locale.US` and device default Locale, which did not solve my problem.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] - the code in your question works fine: http://ideone.com/e1a69c

Comment: As assylias pointed out your formatter seems to work. Please provide more source code. I am super curious about the DATE_IN_FORMAT initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    String dateString = "04 Nov 2016 16:30:07 +0300";

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
    Date date;
    try {
        date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);

        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
        String formatedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        Log.d("Date", formatedDate);

    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Logged Output is

```
11-04 19:21:18.712: D/Date(11703): 2016-11-04 07:00
```